# Dynamic Routing not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So, I have a named route:

```
match 'ip/get/:ip' => 'ip_addresses#show', :via => :get
```

As you can see, I'd like the ip (after 'get') to be dynamic, but I keep getting a routing error when I try it out. Here are my routes:

```
  root        /                     ip_addresses#index
ip_add POST   /ip/add(.:format)     ip_addresses#create
       GET    /ip/add(.:format)     ip_addresses#new
ip_all GET    /ip/all(.:format)     ip_addresses#index
       GET    /ip/get/:ip(.:format) ip_addresses#show
       DELETE /ip/all(.:format)     ip_addresses#destroy
```

And here's my `show` action:

```
def show
  IpAddress.find(params[:id])
end
```

EDIT:  Routing error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ip/get/1.2.3.4"):
```

I've read the Rails Routing from the Outside In Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but naturally I may be overlooking something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what would you like to accomplish ? Looking at the code and the routes I doubt this is a good approach for this problem. Although this is not direct answer to your answer, but I could suggest more cleaner code which does the same.

Comment: Can you share the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Aleks, I agree this could be much cleaner, but I'm basically completing a coding exercise that requests named routes that are RESTful, and in the case of #show, dynamic. If you have suggestions about the code provided, feel free to add them!

Comment: ouh, ok, if it is the coding exercise, then it is ok ;) it is good for practice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question lays in article you gave.

Take a look at section:

> By default dynamic segments don’t accept dots – this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within a dynamic segment add a constraint which overrides this –
>   for example **:id => /[^/]+/** allows anything except a slash.

Look at the example there:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :controller => /admin\/[^\/]+/
```

So in your example I believe it would be:

```
match 'ip/get/:ip' => 'ip_addresses#show', :id => /[^/]+/ , :via => :get
```

And also change `params[:id]` to `params[:ip]`

Comment: Oooooooooh, I read that part earlier, and read it now and was thinking "BUT I DON'T HAVE DOTS, unless you count the colon as dots" and then it hit me that the IP addresses have dots. D'oh. Let me try your suggestions!

Comment: To clarify, my routing action should look like this: `match 'ip/get/:ip => /[^/]+/'=> 'ip_addresses#show', :via => :get`? Sometimes the Rails guides are a little terse for my liking.

Comment: You have also a an example there on the web-page `match 'photos/:id' => 'photos#show', :id => /[A-Z]\d{5}/` , so in your case I believe it would be `match 'ip/get/:ip' => 'ip_addresses#show', :id =>  /[^/]+/ , :via => :get `